# How to close open divs in post loop

Tags: theme-development, loop, themes

I want to add some additional HTML markup to specific posts in a loop. For example in the post loop, I want to wrap the post 3, 4, 5 in two divs `.extra` and `.extra2`

I want to display post in following order: Post 1, 3, 4, 5, 2

I am trying following:

```
<?php if ($query ->current_post == 0) { ?>
    <div> Post # 1</div>
<?php } ?>
<?php if ($query ->current_post == 2) { ?>
    <div class="extra">
        <div class ="extra2>
<?php } ?>  
<?php if ($query ->current_post >= 2) { ?>  
        <div> Post # 3</div>
        <div> Post # 4</div>
        <div> Post # 5</div>
 <?php } ?> 
<?php if ($query ->current_post == 1) { ?>
    <div> Post # 2</div>
 <?php } ?>
```

Now I'm unable to figure out how to close the div `extra` and `extra2` after the post #5 and before the post #2. The number of posts are variable in the loop.

If this method is not correct, please let me know how can I add additional markup for specific posts in the lop. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do it by wrapping closing divs in if condition where current_post is equal to 2. I have added it in following code

```
<?php if ($query ->current_post == 0) { ?>
<div> Post # 1</div>
<?php } ?>
<?php if ($query ->current_post == 2) { ?>
<div class="extra">
    <div class ="extra2>
<?php } ?>  
<?php if ($query ->current_post >= 2) { ?>  
    <div> Post # 3</div>
    <div> Post # 4</div>
    <div> Post # 5</div>
 <?php } ?> 
<?php if ($query ->current_post == 2) { ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
<?php if ($query ->current_post == 1) { ?>
<div> Post # 2</div>
 <?php } ?>
```